# What is the meaning of the symbol "$\left|\underline{\;n\;}\right.$" for integer $n$?

Tags: notation, definition

For example,

> (6) *The sequence of primes is endless.*
>
> For, if $p$ is any prime, the number ${\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}p\\\hline\end{array} + 1}$ is greater than $p$ and is not divisible by $p$ or by any smaller prime. If then ${\begin{array}{|c}p\\\hline\end{array} + 1}$ is not a prime, it must have a prime divisor greater than $p$, and in either case a prime greater than $p$ exists.

And here is another one:

> #### 9. Theorems.
>
> (1) *The product of any $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $\begin{array}{|c}n\\\hline\end{array}$*
>
> For $(m+1)(m+2)...(m+n)/\begin{array}{|c}n\\\hline\end{array} = \begin{array}{|c}\color{red}{m + n}\\\hline\end{array}/\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}m\\\hline\end{array}\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}n\\\hline\end{array}$, and to show that the last expression is an integer it is sufficient to show that any prime $p$ which occurs in $\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}m\\\hline\end{array}\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}n\\\hline\end{array}$ occurs to at least as high a power in $\begin{array}{|c}\color{red}{m+n}\\\hline\end{array}$. Thus we have to show that
>
> $$I[(m+n)/p]+I[(m+n)/p^2]+I[(m+n)/p^3]+... \\
> \geq I[m/p]+I[m/p^2]+I[m/p^3]+... \\
> +I[n/p] +I[n/p^2]+I[n/p^3]+...$$

Comment: I guess it denotes the factorial: $\begin{array}{|c}n\\\hline\end{array}=n!$

Comment: It seems to denote the factorial. It is a quite unusual notation, though. Never seen before.

Comment: @egreg You beat me to it cause I was still thinking how to TeX that symbol :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm a TeX wizard, ain't I? `;-)`

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html In the next battle with egreg, you will be victorious :-)

Comment: It would be good to cite the work in which you found that notation.  More than likely the author defined it earlier in the written text.

Comment: It's used in Ramanujan's notebooks, to denote factorials. I don't suppose he invented it, so I'd guess it was common a century ago. Ramanujan wasn't constrained by TeX, so it didn't cause him any trouble :-)

Comment: Какую книгу Вы читаете?

Comment: It's just like Law of Attraction. I tried to find about this notation for factorial a few days ago. Now it's here.

Comment: I have seen it in very early 20th century textbooks for $n!$

Comment: It would be good to cite the work in general, @hardmath.

Comment: For fun, also find the similar notation for sub-factorials.

Comment: @Crostul ... "quite unusual" ... actually, 100 years ago it was quite common, and notation $n!$ was quite unusual.

Answer (score 41):

In Cajori's "A History of Mathematical Notations", this symbol is attributed to Thomas Jarrett and means $n!$. See article 447 of Cajori's book for the attribution and articles 448 and 449 for the history of its use, mainly in the 19th century.

Comment: At first when you look at the [Wikipedia article Thomas Jarrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jarrett) you think you look at the wrong person, but Wikipedia actually mentions Jarrett's notation for factorial. From Wikipedia you can go to [http://pballew.net/arithme2.html#factor](http://pballew.net/arithme2.html#factor) where more information and references can be found.

Answer (score 22):

This is the notation once used for factorials. I have a copy of Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra (1964 reprint, first published in 1887) that uses this notation. A scan from two pages of the book is at the top of the page https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/factorials/ shows that corner notation defined and also n! is mentioned as another notation that is "sometimes used." Lower down on that webpage are screenshots of the corner factorial notation in work by Eisenhart and Hilbert and at the bottom of the page is a photo at Colorado State from long ago that shows someone using the corner factorial notation at a blackboard.

The Wikipedia page for factorials says the use of ! for factorial was introduced in the early 1800s.

Answer (score 17):

Adding to @Bernard Masse, the history of notations for products of terms in arithmetical progression is quite long. The following is taken from [Christian Kramp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Kramp), 1808, [Elémens d'arithmétique universelle](https://books.google.fr/books?id=w-pSD-UeLRUC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=kramp%20universelle%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9mens&source=bl&ots=8HQLjYYqrX&sig=18QwT93858TwziVCG7NWbY57dyk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpn5nGrfDLAhWGWxoKHeI9C1cQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=kramp%20universelle%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9mens&f=false) ([pdf](http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/332222802/332222802_tif/jpegs/332222802.pdf)), p. XI-XII:

[image: Image of text from a book, transcribed below]

> Pour désigner les produits dont les facteurs constituent entr’eux une progression arithmétique, tels que $a(a+r)(a+2r)....(a+nr-r)$, j’ai conservé la notation $a^{n|r}$, déjà proposée dans mon *analyse des refractions*; je leur avois donné le nom de *facultés*. **Arbogast** lui avoit substitué la dénomination plus nette et plus françoise de *factorielles*; j’ai reconnu l’avantage de cette nouvelle dénomination; et en adoptant son idée, je me suis félicité de pouvoir rendre hommage à la mémoire de mon ami.

where  $1^{p|1}$ would denote the (nowadays) factorial.

He used the term "faculties (facultées en French)", acknowledged [Louis Arbogast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Fran%C3%A7ois_Antoine_Arbogast) for the term "factorial (factorielles)", and on page 348, he introduces the notation $p!$ for $1^{p|1}$ (additional details in [History of notation: "!"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802141/history-of-notation)). You can find this from Article 445 (Volume 2, Page 66) in [Florian Cajori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Cajori), 1993, [A History of Mathematical Notations](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/cajorinot.pdf) (Dover Publications).

From Article 447, Cajori mentions [Thomas Jarrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jarrett) (1805–1882) for his extensive study of algebraic notations, [An essay on algebraic development](https://archive.org/details/essayonalgebraic00jarrrich): containing the principal expansions in common algebra, in the differential and integral calculus, and in the calculus of finite differences, 1831, Page 15,  Article 38, you find:

$$\begin{array}{|c}p\\\hline\end{array}=p(p-1)\ldots 1$$

[image: Image of text from a book, transcribed below]

> The symbol $\underset{n,m}{\begin{array}{|c}a\\\hline\end{array}}$ denotes the product of $n$ factors forming an arithmetical progression, of which the first term is $a$, and the common difference $m$; if $m = -1$, the $m$ may be omitted; and if, in the same case, $n = a$ the $n$ also may be omitted: thus
>
> $\underset{n,m}{\begin{array}{|c}a\\\hline\end{array}} = a(a+m)(a+2m)...(a+\overline{n-1}.m)$,
> $\underset{n\phantom{,m}}{\begin{array}{|c}a\\\hline\end{array}} = a(a-1)(a-2)...(a-n+1)$, and
> ${\begin{array}{|c}a\\\hline\end{array}} = a(a-1)(a-2)...2.1$.

Comment: Why are old books yellow

Comment: @MSE is a dating site : yellow  to books is what grey is to hair. Kramp's 1808 book is older and the scan is whiter

Comment: @LaurentDuval (Most) paper made before about 1850 is more durable than (most) paper made between 1850 and 1980, due to different industrial processes.  The yellowing is a symptom of this.  See https://www.loc.gov/preservation/care/deterioratebrochure.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I made it to this old answer but if you'd like to put $n,m$ underneath, one option is `\underset{n,m}{\begin{array}{|c}p\\\hline\end{array}}=p(p-1)\dots 1` $$\underset{n,m}{\begin{array}{|c}p\\\hline\end{array}}=p(p-1)\dots 1$$

Answer (score 9):

From the context, it seems to mean factorial ($n!=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$). But I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 7):

The first example is a well known proof of Euclid's result about infiniteness of primes; one takes a prime number $p$, then does
$$
N=1+p!
$$
and shows that $N$ is not divisible by $p$ nor by any smaller prime, because each one divides $p!$. So there exists a bigger prime than $p$, because $N>1$ is divisible by a prime. This means
$\begin{array}{|c}p\\\hline\end{array}=p!$ (sorry for the bad emulation of the symbol); it *could* mean the *primorial*, that is, the product of all prime numbers from $2$ up to $p$, but this interpretation would contradict the usage in the second example.