# What does this symbol denote?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I saw this symbol: $\underline{\big|6} $ in a question bank for a chapter of permutations and combinations. I have included the question from the book to provide more context: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDctP.jpg).

Comment: Unless it's just a typo, I have no idea.

Comment: The symbol means $6!$

Comment: That's an old symbol for the factorial of a number. It was mostly phased out by the early 1900s, but you can find it in most 1800s algebra textbooks.

Comment: Use of this symbol is referenced in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802141/history-of-notation#905908) and the comments indicate a usage by Hilbert.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Make an answer out of your comment :)

Comment: @mrtaurho: (and Rajdeep Biswas) I decided to expand my answer by giving some excerpts from Cajori's paper, partly because the paper is behind a paywall and thus many people will not have access to it (indeed, I don't have digital access to it) and partly because it seems that much of what I've found from internet searches is very sparse and repetitive. However, because this question is marked as a duplicate of a question that seems to be a better place for these excerpts, I've posted the excerpts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802141/history-of-notation/3040285#3040285).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This an old symbol for the factorial of a number. It was mostly phased out by the early 1900s, but you can find it in most 1800s literature, especially mathematicians in Great Britain. A useful historical survey of various notations for factorial is given in

Florian Cajori, [*History of symbols for* $\underline{n}=$ *factorial*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/224049), **Isis** 3 #3 (Summer 1921), 414-418.